# How to convert xml response into json response with bash

Tags: bash, curl

I make curl command and the response is in xml format. Is there a way to convert the response in json format, because I need to extract value of one of the tags, i.e.  tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE SiteConfidenceApi PUBLIC "SiteConfidence Api Version current" "url">
<SiteConfidenceApi Version="current">
        <Request></Request>
        <Response Status="Ok" Code="200" Message="Success.">
                <ApiKey Lifetime="3600">value</ApiKey>
        </Response>
</SiteConfidenceApi>
```

Comment: Do you just need to extract a single value? You could use one of several available xml-tools to select a specific xpath. Or do you really need a complete transformation to json?

Comment: only one value, because I will use it in other part of my code

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to extract "value" from element "ApiKey" - this can be done with recent versions of xmllint (depending on your linux distribution, it is usually from libxml2-utils or just libxml2).

```
XML=$(curl "$URL")

echo "$XML" | xmllint --xpath '//ApiKey/text()' -
```

Instead of `//Apikey/text()` you could use even more specific xpath expressions like `/SiteConfidenceApi/Response/ApiKey/text()`

If you have a file from your curl output you could replace "-" (to read from stdin) with the filename as argument to xmllint.

`--xpath` was added to libxml2 with version 2.7.7 in 2010.